# dap-mode for nodejs with nodemon

Tags: javascript, debug

After 5 hours of googling and trying out different configurations i give up.

How do i setup dap-mode for debugging nodejs with nodemon so that the debugger restarts when nodemon restarts?

**Non-solution 1:**

```
//  .vscode/launch.json

 {
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [{
            "type": "node",
            "request": "attach",
            "name": "Node: Nodemon",
            "processId": "${command:PickProcess}",
            "restart": true,
            "port": 9229,
            "protocol": "inspector",
        },
]}
```

starting nodemon with `npm run nodemon --inspect app.js`. Nodemon restarts on code changes, but the debugger does not stop at breakpoints (seems not to run at all, cant find proceses to connect to neither).

**Non-solution 2:**

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch app.js via nodemon",
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "runtimeExecutable": "nodemon",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/app.js",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen"
}
    ]
}
```

Debugger runs, but does not restart on code changes.

Anyone that can confirm that this works for emacs/spacemacs?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I am needing the same solution